# Can "intrude" be used transitively?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions, transitive-verbs

We can say "invade someone's privacy", but can the verb "intrude" be used in the same way without a preposition? As in,

> Don't **intrude** my privacy.

Or should it be:

> Don't **intrude into** my privacy.

Comment: You could, but I don't see why you would. Using _"invade"_ is more common and _"Don't intrude into my privacy."_ sounds clunky to me.

Comment: ... how about "intrude on"? This seems far more standard than "intrude into", if you ask me. "Intrude into" is not a phrase I think I would ever use in any context.

Answer (score 4):

"Intrude" is an intransitive verb so needs the preposition following. I've never seen "intrude" used with any preposition other than "on" but that is a stylistic matter, I think.

"Invade" is transitive and should ***not*** take the preposition.

Answer (score 2):

There **may** be instances where transitive use is possible, but normally a preposition is obligatory after *intrude*.

Answer (score -2):

No, do not use intrude. It does not work. Why? I am not an English professor, but I think intrude intimates a physical trampling of someone's space or conversation, done either on accident, or deliberately. 
Invading means on purpose, with forethought. You don't invade by accident, but you can intrude by accident.
 I hope I helped.